# Primefaces modelling multiple selection trees

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am having a problem related to the modeling of multiple checkbox selection trees in the same page. What i am doing is wrapping each tree in a datagrid like this:

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{evaluationReportController.questionGroups}" var="t" styleClass="top-aligned-grid-cells" columns="1"
                            style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                    <f:facet name="header">Va rugam sa bifati intrebarile</f:facet>
                    <p:panel header="#{t.description}">
                        <p:tree id="question-tree" value="#{t}" var="node" style="width: 100%"
                                selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{evaluationReportController.selectedQuestions[t]}">
                            <p:treeNode>
                                <h:outputText value="#{node}" style="width: 120px"/>
                            </p:treeNode>
                        </p:tree>                            
                    </p:panel>
                </p:dataGrid>
```

The relevant model data from the controller looks like this:

```
private Map<QuestionGroup, TreeNode[]> selectedQuestions;
....
public Map<QuestionGroup, TreeNode[]> getSelectedQuestions() {
    return selectedQuestions;
}

public void setSelectedQuestions(Map<QuestionGroup, TreeNode[]> selectedQuestions) {
    this.selectedQuestions = selectedQuestions;
}
```

However i cant get checkbox selections to the model. Any ideas what i am doing wrong? I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and javaee web API 6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p:dataGrid value="#{evaluationReportController.questionGroups}" var="t" styleClass="top-aligned-grid-cells" 
                        style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                <f:facet name="header">Va rugam sa bifati intrebarile</f:facet>
              <p:column>
                <p:panel header="#{t.description}">
                    <p:tree id="question-tree" value="#{t}" var="node" style="width: 100%"
                            selectionMode="checkbox" selection="#{evaluationReportController.selectedQuestions[t]}">
                        <p:treeNode>
                            <h:outputText value="#{node}" style="width: 120px"/>
                        </p:treeNode>
                    </p:tree>                            
                </p:panel>
                 </p:column>
            </p:dataGrid>
```

Try this code and let me know if the problem still arise. I just removed "Column=1" attribute fron datagrid and add the column explicitly.